# Origins of 'We' Pronoun in Mathematics

Tags: soft-question, math-history

In proofs/books/papers on mathematics the pronoun "we" is usually used. For example:

> In order to derive the quadratic formula **we** first complete the square.
>   Or:
>   ... **we** can deduce this using Euler's theorem ...

etc.

What is the history or origins of using we instead of I? 
Because certainly there is only the author who at that moment is actually doing anything!

In particular then is the "we" a 'royal we' or a collective pronoun?

Comment: I think it means "The author and the reader", assuming that the reader is following the flow of thought that the author is presenting in the text. But I think they are similar (the royal we and the mathematical we) since the former means "God and I" while the latter is "the Reader and I" :D

Comment: It's probably the case that the "we" incorporates the writer and *either* their colleagues *or* the reader. It could very well be both

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/668645/using-we-have-in-maths-papers

Comment: If you want actual *origins* (as in when did it become common and who did it first) it might be worthwhile to ask on [hsm.se].

Answer (score 3):

It's collective. The author is trying to involve *us*  in the work rather than telling us what *they* are doing for us. Sometimes I even write "if *you* complete the square *you* will see ..."